# How to subtract a prefix from a path from find -regex?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I'm writing a script to make symbolic links for my dotfiles, and I'm trying to use find to do this.

I am trying to subtract the prefix from the folder containing my dotfiles so that I only have the relative path so that I can link it into my home directory.

I read that with variables you can do ${string#prefix} if you have the string in a variable, but if I don't, how do I do this?

```
find "$DIR" -regextype posix-extended ! -regex ".*(\.sh|\.git).*" -exec echo ${"{}"#"$DIR"}\;
```

where `$DIR` is the full path of the dotfiles directory

Comment: The regex you're using is dubious -- it will also exclude files like `foo.github-stuff.txt`. But anyways, the `${str#px}` will be expanded by the calling shell _before_ the `find` command is run, so there's no way to fix that approach. Better try something like `find "$SRCDIR" ... your predicates ... -exec echo ln -rst "$DESTDIR" {} +` (read about the `-r` and `-t` options of GNU ln in its manpage, and remove the `echo` if the dry run's OK).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up not `cd`-ing to home before running find and just doing from the source dir `ln -rs {} ~/{}`

Comment: At least with GNU `find`, you can use `-printf '%P'` to output the file's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed